# NSQ Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, nsq, swarm

I'm trying to use NSQ in Docker Swarm without success

mhlg/rpi-nsq is a Docker image built for the Raspberry Pi ARM7 board and I can confirm is working correctly if run as a normal Docker container

Running NSQ in Docker (OK)

```
# crete a bridged network
$ docker network create nsq_network

# run lookupd
$ docker run --name nsqlookupd --network nsq_network -p 4160:4160 -p 4161:4161 mhlg/rpi-nsq nsqlookupd

# run nsqd
$ docker run --name nsqd --network nsq_network -p 4150:4150 -p 4151:4151 mhlg/rpi-nsq nsqd --broadcast-address=nsqd --lookupd-tcp-address=nsqlookupd:4160

# run nsqadmin
$ docker run --name nsqadmin --network nsq_network -p 4171:4171  mhlg/rpi-nsq nsqadmin --lookupd-http-address=nsqlookupd:4161
```

Running NSQ in Docker Swarm mode (FAIL)
this is what I'm doing in the swarm manager

```
# crete an overlay network
$ docker network create nsq_network

# run nsqlookupd
$ docker service create --replicas 1 --name nsqlookupd --network nsq_network -p 4160:4160 -p 4161:4161 mhlg/rpi-nsq nsqlookupd

# run nsqd
$ docker service create --replicas 1 --name nsqd --network nsq_network -p 4150:4150 -p 4151:4151 mhlg/rpi-nsq nsqd --lookupd-tcp-address=nsqlookupd:4160 --broadcast-address=nsqd

# run nsqadmin
$ docker service create --replicas 1 --name nsqadmin --network nsq_network -p 4171:4171  mhlg/rpi-nsq nsqadmin --lookupd-http-address=nsqlookupd:4161
```

If I attach to the nsqd service I can see it is not able to connect to nsqlookupd service.

```
[nsqd] 2016/12/09 16:51:56.851953 LOOKUPD(nsqlookupd:4160): sending heartbeat
[nsqd] 2016/12/09 16:51:56.852049 LOOKUP connecting to nsqlookupd:4160
[nsqd] 2016/12/09 16:51:57.852457 LOOKUPD(nsqlookupd:4160): ERROR PING - dial tcp: i/o timeout
```

It looks like the overlay network create some issues (multicast?) but I can not figure how I can solve it especially on an ARM device.

I tried to ssh into the Docker Host running the nsqd service and exec some dns commands from inside the nsqd container

```
# resolve google.com (OK)
root@3206d1c3cd3d:/# nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.214.78

# resolve nsqd service (OK) - can resolve the container I'm executing the command from
root@e1f6430acd1c:/# nslookup nsqd
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   nsqd
Address: 10.0.0.2

# resolve nsqlookupd service (FAIL)
root@e1f6430acd1c:/# nslookup nsqlookupd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into the same exact issue in docker swarm. This is how I resolved it:

```
docker service create \
--mode global \
--name swarm-master-nsq_nsqlookupd \
--constraint node.role==manager \
--hostname nsqlookupd \
--network name=swarm-master-nsq_nsq,alias=nsqlookupd \
nsqio/nsq:latest /nsqlookupd


docker service create \
--replicas 3 \
--name swarm-master-nsq_nsqd \
--constraint node.role==manager \
--hostname nsqd \
--network name=swarm-master-nsq_nsq,alias=nsqd \
nsqio/nsq:latest sh -c '/nsqd --broadcast-address=$(hostname -i) --lookupd-tcp-address=nsqlookupd:4160'


docker service create \
--replicas 1 \
--publish 4171:4171 \
--name swarm-master-nsq_nsqadmin \
--constraint node.role==manager \
--hostname nsqadmin \
--network name=swarm-master-nsq_nsq,alias=nsqadmin \
nsqio/nsq:latest /nsqadmin --lookupd-http-address=nsqlookupd:4161
```

As far as I can tell, there are a couple issues in your example:

1. You are not aliasing nsqlookupd, and other services
2. the broadcast of nsqd is incorrect (assuming you want to at some point increase the number of nsqd nodes)

Comment: How does this work with 3 replicas of nsqd? Don't you lose messages by topics going to the wrong instance?

Comment: @JoePhillips,  I am not sure what do you mean by "Don't you lose messages by topics going to the wrong instance". I am not very versatile with nsq, but what I think you are saying is that different nsqds could be dedicated to different topics, and the above setup could lead to topics going to wrong nsqds?

From my current understanding(and also for my use case) all nsqd nodes in my setup share the same topics, so for any given topic, messages could be on any of the nsqd nodes and the workers would be responsible for querying every nsqd nodes and retrieving those messages.

Comment: You are right. I didn’t realize you could distribute messages for a single topic across different nsqd instances

Answer (score 0):

You indicate:

```
# crete an overlay network
$ docker network create nsq_network
```

However, that does not create an overlay network but rather a bridge network.
Consider running:

```
docker network create --driver overlay nsq_network
```